# Xpath and MoveToAttribute

Tags: vb.net, xpath, xpathnavigator

I've been trying for a while now to use Xpath (in VB.net) to do the following:

Firstly check every CATEGORY node using the "ID" attribute passed over to the webpage in a querystring, and then once found to assign the "NAME" attribute to a string variable. I've been getting in a muddle trying to use MoveToFirstAttribute(), which is not working.

Here is the sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<STOREITEMS>
<CATEGORY id='123' name='Products'>
<PRODUCT ITEM='456'>
</PRODUCT>
</CATEGORY>
<CATEGORY id='321' name='More Products'>
<PRODUCT ITEM='789'>
</PRODUCT>
</CATEGORY>
</STOREITEMS>
```

I've used the following expression elsewhere on another page to select a specific category so I can then work on the PRODUCT child nodes however I can't select a specific CATEGORY node and then move to its NAME attribute:

```
iter = nav.Select("//CATEGORY[@id=" + Request.QueryString.Get("id") + "]")
```

I would appreciate assistance with the code.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that its `ITEM` attribute is unique, and the `item` is also available in the query string as it was for the `id`, you can use this string to construct an XPath to select a specific `PRODUCT` element:

```
"//PRODUCT[@ITEM=" + Request.QueryString.Get("item") + "]"
```

If a `PRODUCT`'s `ITEM` is only unique with a `CATEGORY`, then use this string to construct the XPath:

```
"//CATEGORY[@id=" + Request.QueryString.Get("id") + "]" + "/PRODUCT[@ITEM=" + Request.QueryString.Get("item") + "]"
```

If any of the above assumptions are incorrect, comment below and we'll adjust.

**Update per comment below:**

Ah, ok, to get the `name` attribute value for a `CATEGORY` given by its `id` attribute:

```
"//CATEGORY[@id=" + Request.QueryString.Get("id") + "]/@name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments. What I'm trying to do is select an entire category of products and then grab the category name ("NAME" attribute) so I can use this as the page header when I list the products on my "products" webpage.

Comment: Hi, hope you can still help with this please? See my comments below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks kjhughes but the following code just assigns the entire contents of the product nodes to the st variable:

```
Dim doc As XPathDocument
Dim nav As XPathNavigator
Dim iter As XPathNodeIterator
Dim count As Integer = 0
Dim st As String

doc = New XPathDocument(AppSettings.Item("SECURED_ASSETS_PATH") & "App_Data/products.xml")
nav = doc.CreateNavigator
iter = nav.Select("//CATEGORY[@id=" + Request.QueryString.Get("id") + "]/@name")
st = iter.Current.Value
```

Comment: Figured it out. I'd not used MoveNext() after selecting